# Take image of div in ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to make T-shirt design website. User customize its t-shirt by putting diffrent div and image over t-shirt div which has t-shirt in background using jquery now after final customization I want to save the picture of t-shirt/div so I can save customization.

How can i save customization div into image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html2canvas library that can render to "canvas" your div and then make it image send it back to you.

You can get the code, and see examples here.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Here is the conversion from canvas to image for get it back:
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

My Concerns.
What if a javascript error appears and the user lose whats make of ?
What if user not use a new modern browser that can handle the "canvas" so that can render to image whats inside the div.

The other way is to use flash and some programming on flash.

Comment: Again, something I dunno but something it alrealy been asked to me. I will test it someday for sure

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'll want to use server side processing to generate your images- rather than a DOM-based approached. You may want to consider using GDI+. Something along these lines should get you started (assuming the context of an ASP.NET page):

**tshirt.aspx**

```
var imagePath1 = @"C:\path\to\tshirt.jpg";
var imagePath2 = @"C:\path\to\graphic.jpg";

var bg = new Bitmap(imagePath1); 
var overlay = new Bitmap(imagePath2);

var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bg);

gfx.DrawImage(overlay, new Point(50, 50));

Response.ContentType="image/jpeg"

bg.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Then on the page where the image is needed:

```
<img src="tshirt.aspx" />
```

Using the same code above for "tshirt.aspx", you can replace the call to `bg.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)` with `bg.Save(filePath, ImageFormat)` to write the generated image to disk.

Comment: As I said these all are user will do customization with Jquery using diffrent time and img control ... so we can not simply merge two images as u shown above.

Comment: @SOFUser (upvote) I actually think this is the *more reliable* way of doing things. Yes, you are doing things on the client side, but that doesn't mean you can't track them on the server side *too* (using jquery/ajax). At the end of the customization, you can have both client and server "know where things are" at a given point. So if choices were A, D, B and X, you can generate the "final render". You gain server side validation as well - if these are for ordering, you **will** want that. Otherwise, if its just for fun, perhaps unnecessary.

Comment: How can I render html table with border color using this? and its width height and all that.. and image inside it text inside it.